# How to run a certain activity in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

For instance, I have a few activities within one app, and in order to see a certain activity's UI or whatever, I need to run a certain activity that is not the launcher of the app.

One stupid way is to build a "door" for that activity in the launcher and go inside the activity from the door. However, Is there any better way to run a certain activity alone?

Comment: unless you make activity as launcher, you cant

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2180283/4281182)

Comment: you want to run it from another app?!! or from the device itself ?!!

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat I want a certain activity that is not the launcher to be run alone in my android device once I click "run" in Android Studio.

Comment: and what prevents you from making it the launcher ?!!

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat Well, It's not a good idea to make an activity a launcher and make it not before long.

Comment: @guo kindly have a look at the new updates to my answer

Answer (score 37):

Very easy. Start by exporting the activity you need to run:

Add `android:exported="true"` in the Activity declaration in the Manifest. This is because `am` is an external application, and you need to export Activities to allow external application to start them.

Go to "Edit Configurations..." in the "Run" menu.

In the left pane, select your application. In the right pane, in the "General" tab, in the "Launch Options" section, there is a "Launch:" dropdown.

Select "Specified Activity", and enter the name of your activity as it appears in your Manifest.

You can create as many Configurations as you like, and name them according however you like, for example to indicate which activity is being started.

Comment: is there a way we can pass some extra to the activity from configuration?

Comment: Check the option: Skip activity validation in case if your validation is dependent on some validations.

Answer (score 5):

I am using Android Studio stable version 2.1.2 and there is one shortcut to do so. `Just open the activity class you wish to run and right click on coding area`, There is options to run and debug the particular activity as shown in below screen shot.

For windows use **shortcut** <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and for mac use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. I have tested this in emulator and its working fine, didn't test in actual device.Works only for activity class and don't forget to put cursor in coding area by clicking on it. Also I am not aware whether this option available in older Android studio versions less than 2.1.2.

[image]

Comment: I have tested. If the activity is also the launcher, then this way works well. However, if not, this way didn't work.

Comment: I have tested with activity that is not launcher works well. Kindly try with activity other than launcher.

Comment: As stated by njzk2's answer, you have to add `android:exported="true"` to the activity's properties in the manifest in order to make this work for a non-launcher activity.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10961409/1638739), you can easily achieve that by giving the activity an action name in the **manifest.xml** of the app:

```
<activity android:name="Activity3" ... >
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.company.package.FOO"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

then create the following `intent` from anywhere in order to run this activity specifically:

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.company.package.FOO"));
```

---

After your clarification that the activity has to be run firstly when running the app instead of the launcher, you can achieve that by not setting the content of the launcher activity and instead create an intent that runs the wanted activity:

**MainActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout); // remove this line

    Intent intent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, WantedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("EXIT", false);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: This is the "door" way I have metioned

Comment: there isn't another way, the launcher activity will be the launcher activity

Answer (score 1):

Add exported true Manifest declaration of that activity.

Go to that activity, right click anywhere, go will get certain option with a 'Run XYZ Activity' option too. just run it

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name=".phoneVideo">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: could add a few words of explanation, please?

Comment: add this code in the mainfest.xml file in the area of file which you want to run @RealCheeseLord

Comment: @RealCheeseLord see as i have added in the new image . I place this code inside the activity name as .phoneVideo which i want to run first

Comment: thank you, it was just a general suggestion, I don't need it for myself :D

Comment: I'm sorry, but did you really have to move the entry point? Since exported also works.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have two or more activities in your app to start with. Let's say you want to  go to a certain activity in your app to display first. May be for testing purposes or any other. Let's see how it can be done,
First you need to find the **AndroidManifest.xml** file. Its there under the manifests folder.
[According to this first dispaly activity is MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLixT.jpg)

Lets's say I want to make the **home** activity display first. So what I have to do is simply cut the intent-filter.../intent-filter and paste it within home activity. [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgiM0.jpg)

First Displaying Acivity is MainActivity according to this,

```html
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".home">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

When we want to make the **home** acivity display first simplay change it as this,

```html
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".home">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>
```

This should work. Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

For my example, the specific activity was called Activity2 and the project was called ScreenSizes

1- Open the Android Manifest: app>manifests>AndroidManifest.xml

2- Change the activity section for the specific activity to include android:exported="true" like this:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity2"
      android:exported="true">
</activity>
```

3- Open the java class of the specific activity: app>java>com.example.(your app name)>(specific activity)

in my case it was: app>java>com.example.screensizes>Activity2

4- Right click anywhere in the blank/white area of the Java file and select the option Run '(activity name)'

in my case it was: Run 'Activity2'

Comment: Why is this not an option for me?