# Kotlin running certain activity and accessing class object

Tags: android, kotlin

I followed this guide ([How to run a certain activity in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308161/how-to-run-a-certain-activity-in-android-studio)) to launch another activity aside from my main.

I have a GetUser.xml and ShowUser.xml layouts.
In GetUser.xml, user can enter their name and age.

I have a user class with constructor that takes in name and age inside GetUser.kt. I initialize User object with the values : name, age  I got from the input fields in GetUser.

Now when I run the other activity ShowUser, I wish to access this object so I can get the values and display it in ShowUser.xml

My question is how do I access this object from the GetUser.kt and use it in ShowUser.kt ?

Comment: (1) Send the data as `Intent` from GetUser to ShowUser activity. (2) Store data as `SharedPreferences`. (3) Ugly solution: Create a global object holding the data as properties.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are looking for `extra`.

When starting one `Activity` from another, you can pass data via `extra`.

Let's say you have a class `Person` with `String name` and `int age`.

There are 2 simple ways to to this.

**1. Send data separately**

Because `Person` is a simple class that consists of 2 member fields, we can pass each data separately and combine into `Person` in started `Activity`.

We need `Intent` to do this.

```
val p = Person(name, age) // Person data
val intent = Intent(this, NewActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra('name', p.name)
intent.putExtra('age', p.age)
startActivity(intent)
```

On started `NewActivity`'s `onCreate()`, you can receive this data and make an object out of it.

```
val name = intent.getStringExtra('name')
val age = intent.getIntExtra('age')
val combinedPersonData = Person(name, age)
```

**2. Send whole instance**

If the class you are trying to send is too big to use method 1, you can try sending it as itself.

To do this, you need to implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable` to your class.

```
class Person(val name: String, val age: Int): Serializable { ... }
```

Make sure all of the members in the class are also Serializable or are primitive types.

With this, you can send the person object as serializable object.

```
val p = Person(name, age) // Person data
val intent = Intent(this, NewActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra('person', p)
startActivity(intent)
```

In the receiver's `onCreate()`,

```
val p = intent.getSerializableExtra('person') as Person
```

will receive the while `Person` data.