# Android - How to run only specific activities?

Tags: android, debugging, testing

Working on my project I'm gettin annoyed everytime I run my app, it starts from the very beginning and I want to test/debug/check only the activity I'm working on.

I want to run the app and start at the activity that I'm working on

I found this: [how to run Specific activity in android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176037/how-to-run-specific-activity-in-android-emulator)

Seems a good option, I'd like to know more ways to achieve what I want to do

- Android Studio 2.2.2
- Ubuntu 16.04 x64
- No emulator (yet), using real device

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html

Comment: Also, when testing and making code changes, you can use `startActivity()` to start whatever you want in the `onCreate()` of your launcher Activity

Comment: you can try to use the instant run..